# GCE: How to get instance type from SSH shell?

Tags: shell, google-compute-engine

In Amazon AWS there is an option to fetch information about the instance you are on by making HTTP request to meta data like:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

Particularly if you need to know instance type you can use

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
```

No special tools are required. Is there anything like AWS metadata at Google Compute Engine so that one can get instance info without specifying project/instance name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's at: `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/`

The specific key you'r looking for is at:

`http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type`

See the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#querying).